# Cannot find module 'react-dnd' from 'index.js', However, Jest was able to find: "../../my_component.js"

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I am using 'react-sortable-tree' npm package in my current project(creating a component with it) which have external dependency of 'react-dnd'.

While rendering, the component looks just fine, but while testing same component using jest, it throws :-

Cannot find module 'react-dnd' from 'index.js'

```
However, Jest was able to find:
    '../../../src/MyComponent.js'

You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['', 'js', 'jsx', 'json'].

See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:259:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/frontend-collective-react-dnd-scrollzone/lib/index.js:24:17)
```

My present jest.config.js looks like :-

```
module.exports = {
"setupFiles": [
    "<rootDir>/enzyme.config.js"
],
transformIgnorePatterns: ["/!node_modules"], //basically allowing jest to transform everything in node _modules
transform: { 
    '.*': 'babel-jest'
},
moduleFileExtensions: ['','js', 'jsx', 'json']
};
```

I am working around it for a day but couldn't find out the bug. Can anyone help or advice on this.Thanks in advance.
Version info :-

1. Babel : 7
2. Jest : 24.9
3. babel-jest : 24.9

Comment: You are setting `testPathIgnorePatterns` to `node_modules` – the `react-dnd` pattern is located in `node_modules`, hence ignored by Jest, I'm pretty sure this is causing the error

Comment: Results are same after removing `testPathIgnorePatterns` key from config.

Comment: Uploaded the updated jest.config.js.